How to draw circle or arc using d3, by points excluding radius and angle?
In fact, I succeeded to put d3 lines, d3 circles and d3 arcs with radius and angles.
but to draw objects in line with scales (x-scale / y-scale), i found that it is ambiguous to apply scale to radius of circles and arcs.
So, now I changed and I'm looking for a way to draw d3 circles or d3 arcs by using points. The points can be calculated by using radius * cos / sin, and then the points could be scaled.
I made a path function like below
function d3_path( apts ){

    var sPath;
    
    sPath = "";

    sPath = "M " + apts[0]['x'] + " " + apts[0]['y'] + " C ";

    for( var i = 1 ;  i < apts.length ; i++) {

        sPath += apts[i]['x'] + " " + apts[i]['y'] ;

    }        

    return sPath

}


and then tried to draw circle and arc like below
ARC
            var vertex = [];

            for( var j = 0; j < dataGroup[i].values.length; j++ ){
                var iposi = vertex.length;
                vertex[iposi] = [];
                vertex[iposi]['x'] = xscale( dataGroup[i].values[j].x );
                vertex[iposi]['y'] = yscale( dataGroup[i].values[j].y );
            }

            og.select("#layer" + dataGroup[i].values[0].layer )
            .append('svg:path') 
            .attr("id", dataGroup[i].values[0].name )               
            .attr('d', d3_path( vertex ) )  
            .attr('stroke-width', dwidth_out + 'px') 
            .attr('fill', 'none');

CIRCLE
          var vertex = [];

            for( var j = 0; j < dataGroup[i].values.length; j++ ){
                var iposi = vertex.length;
                vertex[iposi] = [];
                vertex[iposi]['x'] = xscale( dataGroup[i].values[j].x );
                vertex[iposi]['y'] = yscale( dataGroup[i].values[j].y );
            }

            og.select("#layer" + dataGroup[i].values[0].layer )
            .append('svg:path') 
            .attr("id", dataGroup[i].values[0].name )               
            .attr('d', d3_path( vertex ) + " Z" )  
            .attr('stroke-width', dwidth_out + 'px') 
            .attr('fill', 'none');

but the circles and arcs are shown incorrectly.
Please give some comments.

I don't see anything in your post that's related to Bezier curves, did you mis-tag your post?

Seems like you're passing vertices to a cubic bezier command - won't work. You're searching for a arc-to-cubic approximation
